# Rellenar datos de un popup en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

Tengo una lista de testimonios, cada uno con su botón de modificar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al apretar el botón verde de modificar me abre este popup que me sirve para modificar el que haya apretado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que al abrirse el popup me rellene con los mismos datos de título y testimonio según el que haya apretado

Este es mi form del boton verde

```
<form method="POST" id="formIdModi" name="formIdModi">
    <button type="button" name="{{$datoTesti->userId}}" id="{{$datoTesti->userId}}" value="{{$datoTesti->ratingId}}" class="btn btn-success btn-modifi" disabled>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                            
     </button>
     <input type="hidden" name="ratingId" id="question_id" value="{{$datoTesti->ratingId}}"> 
</form>
```

Este mi formulario del popup

```
@section('modificarTestimonio')
    <div class="overlay_modi" id="modiSection" style="display:none;">
        <div class="popup_modi">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <form id="modiForm" method="POST" action="{{route('rutaFormModi')}}">   
                @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h3>Modificar testimonio y valoración</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rateButtonUp" aria-label="Left Align"> 
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButtonUp" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButtonUp" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButtonUp" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-grey btn-sm rateButtonUp" aria-label="Left Align">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="ratingUp" name="ratingUp" value="1">
                    </div>      
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="ratingIdx" name="ratingIdx" value="xd">
                    <div id="tb">
                        
                    <!-- { $datos ?? '' }} -->
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usr">Título*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Escriba un título..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Testimonio*</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Escriba un testimonio..." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-info" id="saveReview">Modificar testimonio</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="cancelModi">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                                
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

y mi javascript para saber el id del que quiero modificar

```
var z = document.getElementById('idUsuarioActual').value;
    $('button[name="'+z+'"]').click(function (e) {
        $("#modiSection").show();
        $(this).addClass('seleccionado');
        var id = $('button[class="btn btn-success btn-modifi seleccionado"]').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('seleccionado');
        $("#ratingIdx").val(id);
    });
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y cambia las imágenes por código en texto para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Opción 1: Podrías usar un if para renderizar desde blade dependiendo de la califacación seleccionada.

Opción 2: Si es desde JS, en este caso JQuery, recomendaría a cada botón crearle un id único y le remueves o aplicas la clase seleccionado dependiendo del valor votado antes.
Por ej:

```
if (valAnterior==1) {
   $("#idBtn1').addClass('seleccionado');
   $("#idBtn1').removeClass('seleccionado');
   $("#idBtn1').removeClass('seleccionado');
   $("#idBtn1').removeClass('seleccionado');
   $("#idBtn1').removeClass('seleccionado');
} else if....
```

así sucesivamente hasta 5